# Loop through two lists if list maybe None or size of two list maybe different

Tags: python

what is the best way for me to iterate through two lists like following. the only things is two lists maybe None or size is different
I cannot use zip because list maybe None or size maybe different, I cannot use concatenation neither because one of list maybe None

```
iter1 = [1,2,3,4]
iter2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for a in (iter1+iter2):
    print(a)
============
output
1
2
3
4
a
b
c
d
e

iter1 = None
iter2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
a
b
c
d
e

iter1 = None
iter2 = None
nothing print
```

Comment: What is the desired output when the lists are different lengths or None?

Comment: If the list is `None` then you can't iterate through it. Can't you just conditionally concatenate if they're both not `None`? Otherwise, iterate through the other list.

Comment: You say you have two lists, then you say they may be `None`.  Which is it?

Comment: @Chris_Rands, i would like to iterate whatever element in both list. so if size is different, I would like to have both element. same as one is None

Comment: Show the actual output in your question, maybe like `list(itertools.zip_longest(iter1 or [], iter2 or []))` ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'm thinking that or `itertools.chain(iter1 or [], iter2 or [])`. Of course, I would not use the hacky boolean `or` way, rather, I'd assign the results of two seperate conditional expressions to intermediate variables and then use chain...

Comment: I quite like `iter1 or []` to deal with iter1 possibly being None.

Comment: @NedBatchelder it was idiomatic before conditional expressions, from what I understand, but it's always felt hackey to me. I guess it is an idiom in many languages to use boolean operators like that. Maybe I'm just a curmudgeon, or I just spend too much time in higher-level languages.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you'd rather `[] if iter1 is None else iter1`? seems overly verbose to me. `or` only seems bad where there might be *other* falsy values to confuse things

Comment: @Chris_Rands yeah, I would prefer something like `it1 = <conditional expression>; it2 = <conditional_expression>; for x in chain(it1, it2): ...` but I might have a higher tolerance for verbosity. I like being able to read my code months later without thinking "wait, what was I doing here?", granted, as I stated, `x or y` is definitely idiomatic, I just started coding after that fell out of favor when Python added a conditional expression, so when I see it, it still makes me pause and think. I came late to the programming world, and was spoiled by Python I suppose

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga fair enough, probably you are right that readability really is more important. Anyway, the only idiom like this I really dislike is `[iter1, []][iter1 is None]` but this fortunately rare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for item in (iter1 or []) + (iter2 or []):
    print item
```